# What should be used whether/that

Tags: conjunctions

In the following sentence which word is correct?

She does not believe ___________ Mr. Sharma can help her.

The two options are

1. Whether
2. That

According to me it should be **that** because **she** is completely sure that **Mr. Sharma can not help her**. But my teacher says it should be **whether**.

Answer (score 2):

"She does not believe whether..." can't happen in English (I'm a native speaker of American English).

"She does not *know* whether..." would be fine.

Comment: Paul T. is quite right and so are you. Only 'That' fits.

Answer (score 0):

*Whether* (=*whether or not*) is *logically* impossible here because the verb *to believe* (unlike e. g. the verb 'to know', possible in its place) doesn't allow for *mutually exclusive* options (can or cannot here) and usually deals with something definite. So '*that*' is the correct choice for this sentence.